# Construction of the Weierstrass $\wp$ function

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-functions

In the construction of the Weierstrass $\wp$-function, why do we have to add a leading term $\frac{1}{z^2}$ instead of letting $\wp(z)=\sum_{\omega\neq0}\left\{\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right\}$? I am guessing this is to take care of the origin too.

Comment: You have a sum over $w$, but no $w$ in the summand.

Comment: Are you still here? Would you like to engage with comments and answers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes! Could you clarify you previous comment? Are you saying that the leading term assigns a pole at the origin, just like at all other periods?

Comment: I'm saying you have written $\sum_{w\ne0}$, which makes me expect that what comes next will have the symbol $w$ in it somewhere, but what comes next is $$\left\{{1\over(z-\omega)^2}-{1\over\omega^2}\right\}$$ which has no $w$ in it. I'm also saying you have had nothing to say about the answer that was posted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I am sorry for the confusion, I have corrected my typo. Make sense to you now？

Comment: Much better. Now, will you engage with the answer that was posted yesterday?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I would never disregard an answer to my question, and I reply whenever I got a breath. I appreciate you for pointing out the typo, but despise the air in which you give commands without sharing real expertise.

Comment: I gave no commands. I saw no need to share any expertise, in the light of the answer posted by user1952009. I'm happy to see that you have engaged with that user. We all win. Let's be happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not obvious that $$\wp(z) = \frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 \setminus (0,0)} \frac{1}{(z-nw_1-mw_2)^2}-\frac{1}{(nw_1-mw_2)^2}\tag{1}$$
is doubly periodic.

What is obvious is that $\frac{1}{(z-nw_1-mw_2)^2}-\frac{1}{(nw_1-mw_2)^2} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{|nw_1+mw_2|^3})$ so that $(1)$ converges uniformly on any compact $\subset \mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda$,

thus $\wp(z)$ is meromorphic  and 
$$\wp'(z) = \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{-2}{(z-nw_1-mw_2)^3}$$
which is obviously $w_1,w_2$ periodic and meromorphic.

Finally, say that for any $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda$ : $$\wp(z+w_1)-\wp(z) =\int_z^{z+w_1} \wp'(s)ds $$ $$= \sum_{(n,m) \in \mathbb{Z}^2} \frac{1}{(z+w_1-nw_1-mw_2)^2}-\frac{1}{(z-nw_1-mw_2)^2} = 0$$
and hence $\wp(z)$ is $w_1$ periodic. Do the same with $w_2$, and you get that $\wp(z)$ is a meromorphic function that is $w_1,w_2$ periodic with one double pole at each $z =nw_1+mw_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So without the term $\frac{1}{z^2}$, $\wp(z)$ would not be periodic?

Comment: @LTW nor periodic, nor doubly periodic, since $1/z^2$ isn't ${}{}$